# Pinpoint & SNS Filters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I have two way SMS setup with Pinpoint where the incoming SMS gets sent to an SNS Topic.  I'd like to re-use this SNS topic for other phone numbers that are using two way.  However, the subscribers to that topic will need to only see messages for the phone number that that particular subscriber is concerned with.

I know about subscription filter policies.  However, the incoming SMS doesn't have a "Message Attributes" key and I haven't seen a way I can promote the "to" phone number or "keyword" to the message attribute so I can filter on it.

Is there a way to parse the body of the message to create the filter for a subscription?

Answer (score 0):

There are no properties of a two way message that are promoted to be filtered on.  I ended up sending the message to a lambda that promotes the properties I needed and re-published the message to another topic.  I then had subscription filters subscribed to that topic.